# PHP match multiple whole words in regex

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to match a string for word1 or word but a string like 'this is a testword' should NOT give a match. I'm trying to do `preg_match('/^\b(word|word1)\b/i',$string)` but no luck

Comment: can you post a sample of the string you are trying to match on

Comment: so it is working and I need to go home and get some rest. Thanks still though :). And yeah if you look at those I didn't accept well it's because it there weren't any appropriate answers, it's not a competition to get stats up but to actually get help. Thanks again guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine if you remove the `^` from the beginning of your RegEx ..

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is the `^` at the start:

```
preg_match('/\b(word|word1)\b/i',$string);
```

Note that the `^` denotes the beginning of the string, so you are looking for something that starts with the options you are giving.